# Maximum value and minimum value

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm having trouble getting the answer to this math problem. I've been trying the extreme value theorem but it comes to nothing :(. I will be attentive to your answers, thank you ;).

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and $T>0$ such that $f(x+T)=-f(x) \forall{x\in{\Bbb R}}$. Prove that the function $f$ has a maximum value and a minimum value.

Comment: Hint: what is $f(x + 2T)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested in the hint, consider $f(x + 2T) = f((x + T) + T) = -f(x + T) = -1 \cdot -f(x) = f(x)$
So, $f$ is periodic with period $2T$.

On any segment $[x, x + 2T]$, because $f$ is continious,  by the extreme value theorem, we have that $f$ attains its maximum and minimum on some $[x, x + 2T], x \in \mathbb{R}$, and because $f(x + 2T) = f(x)$ we do not need to consider other values of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).